# GPU for deep learning wsl on win 11

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, gpu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

[image: Before I ran the model]I see windows recognizes both the GPUs and i see the attached output. for Disp.A it shows off. I am assuming gpu.1 is not being used for display. But when I run my T5 model(pytorch)[image: after picture of nvidia-smi output], it throws an error saying CUDA trying to allocate 20MB but there is no memory available(OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 20.00 MiB (GPU 0; 8.00 GiB total capacity; 7.36 GiB already allocated; 0 bytes free; 7.36 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF
). when I run nvidia-smi from the wsl (using conda) I see second GPU memory is completely free. How do I ensure the model is using both GPUs?